# Shem Yosef on Mishne Torah?

Tags: rambam

Who authored the Shem Yosef commentary on Rambam's [Mishneh Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah)? This work is featured on the online bar-ilan database.

Comment: What have you checked? In what editions is it found?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have not found it as a separate sefer. It isnt in the otzar mefarshei yad hachazaka either. I saw it on the online bar ilan, but I dont know how to find the author without a subscription.

Comment: Don't you think it would be worth including that information in the question so if someone has a subscription they could check??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is probably by [Rabbi Yisrael Chaim Yosef Elyakim](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=12577&bid=342&hilite=), (d. 1791), based on the information at [Invaluable.com](http://www.invaluable.com/auction-lot/shem-yosef-salonika,-1769-glosses-by-author-418-c-f00bdb9010).

You can see the original 400 page long work Shem Yosef [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/7497).

Bio from [HebrewBooks.com](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=12577&bid=342&hilite=):

Rabbi Yisrael Chaim Yosef Elyakim printed his work Shem Yosef in 1769 in Salonika. He was born in Sofia (Bulgaria) and died in Jerusalem on Rosh Chodesh Iyar 5551 - 5 May 1791

> מחכמי סופיאה (בולגריה) ושם חיבר את ספרו כנזכר בשער, עלה לארץ ישראל ונפטר בירושלים ביום ר"ח אייר שנת תקנ"א (1791). על מצבתו נחרט:‏
>   
>  *מ"ק איש הבינים, חכם לב, צדיק באמונתו הוא הרב המובהק כהר"ר ישראל חיים יוסף אליקים תנצב"ה, והיתה מנוחתו כבוד ביום ר"ח אייר תקנ"א*.‏
>   
>  בנו רבי יחיאל יעקב אליקים (חתן המקובל רבי דוד מאג'ר שהיה תלמיד הרש"ש ומגדולי חכמי ישיבת המקובלים בית אל) בחתימת שמו להקדמות הספרים שהוציא לאור בשאלוניקי (יד רמ"ה – סנהדרין, שו"ת מהר"י ברונא ושו"ת "נהרות דמשק") מתארו "הרב המובהק חסיד ועניו מאוד". ‏
>   
> רבי יוסף כותב על עצמו בשער בענוות חן "זה קרבן עני מנחת חוטא אשר חיברתי פה עיר תהלה סופיאה יע"א עני אני במדות ובדעות שפל אנשים בטל במיעוטו מדרך כף רגל לכל העובר איש צעיר חיים יוסף אליקים".‏
>   
> . פרטים ביבליוגרפיים:
>   רבי יוסף הדפיס את ספרו בשאלוניקי בשנת תקכ"ט (1769) (יתכן שהדפיס את הספר בשאלוניקי בעברו שם בדרכו לארץ ישראל).‏